# execute a bat file using php installed in different drive

Tags: php, batch-file, windows-xp, exec, drive

when I run `exec('C:\execute\batfile.bat');` it works when my xampp is installed in 
C:

but when I move my codes in another server the xampp there is installed in 
D:

so my code `exec('D:\execute\batfile.bat');` fails and doesn't show any errors when I test in browser.

Please help on how to run a bat file not saved in C:

Thank you so much

Comment: First step is to replace the contents of batfile.bat with something simple - like `echo THIS IS A TEST > somefile.txt` This should tell if the file is being executed (you look to see if somefile.txt is created) If it passes it's your code in the batch file and you need to debug it.

Comment: hi @preet sangha. thanks for your reply i tried it. But when I run the bat file using the browser still it doesn't work. But when I click the bat file it works. I change the code into flexible one `<?php
echo exec('execute\batfile.bat');
?>`

Comment: You need to check the PHP excution logs and also the wdinwos logs. Until you know what's failing you're running blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your suggestion and solutions :)

I follow the suggestion of @preet sangha and find "ERROR: The parameter is incorrect".

Then I researched more on what is the cause of incorrect parameter. Then I stumble upon the answer of juan at laluca and ernestokarim in http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php. And I follow the answer of ernestokarim

> Start > Run > "services.msc"
>
> Search the Apache Service, right click and select Properties.
>
> You will see two radio buttons, check the first if it isn't, and then
>   check too the check box below.
>   [image: Under Log On Tab]
>
> Now restart Apache

I realize that for some reason when xampp is installed in C, function exec works fine but when you installed it in other drive it doesn't because of some permission issues. 
The above steps solve my dilemma :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing the output, maybe you're just missed something inside the bat file and it's not a php problem

```
echo system("D:\execute\batfile.bat");
```

Comment: thanks @imer. i also tried system but not working. I'm puzzled because when xampp is installed in C: there's no problem but when installed in other drive it doesn't even output a print.